# System.Data.Entities runtime error with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, web-config

I am very new to .NET MVC and am getting this runtime error

```
CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly 
that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity,     
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

It seems to be a pretty frequent problem, but all of the solutions are to add an assembly in the web.config file. I do not have an assemblies section in the web.config. I am using the razor view engine. Thank you, and I have added the reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project.
2. Choose Add Reference
3. On .NET tab, select reference System.Data.Entity and click OK

Comment: @Eric It may be you need to add assembly control on your Views folder

Comment: @Eric, I mean in web.config in Views folder